# PHPExcel Writer Excel2007 error

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I recently encountered this error in my report.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3022731 bytes)
```

I cant seem to resolved the problem, i already added:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```

in my script but it seems the issue is still persistent, by the way im using

```
PHPExcel ver 1.7.6
```

My excel file output contains 55 headers and multiple worksheets (closely 45 - increasing) and each sheet contains about 150 to 500 records

I would like to seek for your help and advises to resolve my remedy T_T

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest upgrading PHPExcel to a more recent version (1.7.6 is over 6 years old now), and look at using Cell Caching

Comment: sir @MarkBaker, i just downloaded your latest PHPExcel while reading some solutions on the net: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel ive done some testings and im pretty new of this cell caching feature

Comment: [Documentation on Cell Caching](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md#cell-caching)

Comment: @MarkBaker ive used the cache_in_memory_gzip for this, i think, its more efficient to used..another thing, ive observed that every creation of a new sheet per loop, it begins to slow, is there a tweak to on that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to import the Excel File into an Access Database and then query the database via ODBC from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet - it`s the rewritten version of PhpExcel. It works way better. I know, because I have used both.

If that does not help your problem you should use caching see: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/memory_saving/

P.S. if you will be using sqlite3 caching make sure you have the proper extension php-sqlite3 installed, because it fails silently and does not cache if extension is not there.